# Knex - Combine multiple dot functions into one

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js

How can I combine multiple knex dot functions into one large dot function?

For example I have this query:

```
await knex
    .from(common)
    .select('x','y')
    .innerJoin(table1, `${table2}.id`, `${table1}.table2_id`)
    .whereNull(`${table1}.date`)
    .whereNull(`${table1}.file`)
    .where({
        field1: 1,
        field2: 2
    })
```

The inner join and whereNull statements are common to a few other queries. Is it possible to extract this part

```
.innerJoin(table1, `${table2}.id`, `${table1}.table2_id`)
.whereNull(`${table1}.date`)
.whereNull(`${table1}.file`)
```

and replace with one function, `.joinWhereNull`.

Then the original query could be rewritten like this:

```
await knex
    .from(common)
    .select('x','y')
    .joinWhereNull()
    .where({
        field1: 1,
        field2: 2
    })
```

I have tried writing custom functions like this

```
const joinWhereNull = () => {
    return (query) => {
        return query
           .innerJoin(table1, `${table2}.id`, `${table1}.table2_id`)
           .whereNull(`${table1}.date`)
           .whereNull(`${table1}.file`)
    }
}
```

However this feels clunky to use and I found the `select` statement needs its own function too, otherwise it is called prematurely.

Is there an easier way to combine knex functions?

***Edit***
Also tried using a custom QueryBuilder:

```
Knex.QueryBuilder.extend('joinWhereNull', function (table1, table2) {
    return this
        .innerJoin(table1, `${table2}.id`, `${table1}.table2_id`)
        .whereNull(`${table1}.date`)
        .whereNull(`${table1}.file`)
})
```

However, I get a type error saying that joinWhereNull is not a function.

Comment: Your clunky solution is the best solution in this use case in my opinion. I'd suggest you put this in a helper class with other such functions with you can utilize where needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the QueryBuilder approach as shown here: [Extending Query Builder](https://knexjs.org/#:%7E:text=Extending%20Query%20Builder).

However, TypeScript will give type error unless you extend the QueryBuilder interface with `joinWhereNull` function. The instructions to do that are in the same page: [Extending Query Builder](https://knexjs.org/#:%7E:text=Extending%20Query%20Builder).

Quoting here:

> 1. Create a knex.d.ts file inside a @types folder (or any other folder).
>
> ```js
> // knex.d.ts
>
> import { Knex as KnexOriginal } from 'knex';
>
> declare module 'knex' {
>   namespace Knex {
>     interface QueryBuilder {
>       customSelect<TRecord, TResult>(value: number): KnexOriginal.QueryBuilder<TRecord, TResult>;
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> 2. Add the new @types folder to typeRoots in your tsconfig.json.
>
> ```json
> // tsconfig.json
>
> {
>   "compilerOptions": {
>     "typeRoots": [
>       "node_modules/@types",
>       "@types"
>     ],
>   }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there are multiple QueryBuilder instances at play. So defining the new method on one instance is not working. We can set the new method to QueryBuilder.prototype so it will be available on all the instances.
Following code worked in my test environment:

```js
const knex = require('knex')({ client: 'sqlite3', connection: { filename: './mydb.sqlite' }});

let common = 'common';
let table1 = 'table1';
let table2 = 'table2';
let field1 = 'field1';
let field2 = 'field2';

// using default methods
console.log('one: ',
 knex
  .from(common)
  .select('x', 'y')
  .innerJoin(table1, `${table2}.id`, `${table1}.table2_id`)
  .whereNull(`${table1}.date`)
  .whereNull(`${table1}.file`)
  .where({
   field1: 1,
   field2: 2,
  })
  .toString()
);

// define the new method
//knex.queryBuilder().__proto__['joinWhereNull'] = function () {
Object.getPrototypeOf(knex.queryBuilder())['joinWhereNull'] = function () {
 return this.innerJoin(table1, `${table2}.id`, `${table1}.table2_id`)
  .whereNull(`${table1}.date`)
  .whereNull(`${table1}.file`);
};

// using our method
console.log('two: ',
 knex
  .from(common)
  .select('x', 'y')
  .joinWhereNull()
  .where({
   field1: 3,
   field2: 4,
  })
  .toString()
);
```

Output:

```
one:  select `x`, `y` from `common` inner join `table1` on `table2`.`id` = `table1`.`table2_id` where `table1`.`date` is null and `table1`.`file` is null and `field1` = 1 and `field2` = 2
two:  select `x`, `y` from `common` inner join `table1` on `table2`.`id` = `table1`.`table2_id` where `table1`.`date` is null and `table1`.`file` is null and `field1` = 3 and `field2` = 4
```

---

I don't have much idea about how the library internally works. But found following comment in the code:
**make-knex.js**

```js
  // Allow chaining methods from the root object, before
  // any other information is specified.
  //
  // TODO: `QueryBuilder.extend(..)` allows new QueryBuilder
  //       methods to be introduced via external components.
  //       As a side-effect, it also pushes the new method names
  //       into the `QueryInterface` array.
  //
  //       The Problem: due to the way the code is currently
  //       structured, these new methods cannot be retroactively
  //       injected into existing `knex` instances!  As a result,
  //       some `knex` instances will support the methods, and
  //       others will not.
  //
  //       We should revisit this once we figure out the desired
  //       behavior / usage.  For instance: do we really want to
  //       allow external components to directly manipulate `knex`
  //       data structures?  Or, should we come up w/ a different
  //       approach that avoids side-effects / mutation?
  //
  //      (FYI: I noticed this issue because I attempted to integrate
  //       this logic directly into the `KNEX_PROPERTY_DEFINITIONS`
  //       construction.  However, `KNEX_PROPERTY_DEFINITIONS` is
  //       constructed before any `knex` instances are created.
  //       As a result, the method extensions were missing from all
  //       `knex` instances.)
```

Comment: This gives an error
    TypeError: knex.queryBuilder is not a function

Comment: Get reference to any QueryBuilder object instance.  Log the `knex` object to the console using `console.log('%O', knex)` and look for querybuilder object. There is also a query builder object in `knex.context`  or try `knex.QueryBuilder`.